# Graphics in VHDL for Pong game

Tags: vhdl

I am making a VHDL programmed classic pong game on a zedboard. The game is fully working now and i want to add some graphics like for example a scoreboard.

Is it possible to do graphics like this in VHDL and can I do it without trying to add in pixels manually?

Comment: We need a lot more information as the zed board has a CPU and FPGA. Where are the pong graphics coming from? My guess is writing pixels by the CPU is a lot less work then trying to make an overlay video with a graphics ROM.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do  ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes and no.....